# Visual Studio 2015: LNK1104 - Root Cause: All folders are "Read Only"

Tags: windows-7-x64, readonly

I was compiling a DLL and an application, suddenly "LNK1104: cannot open exe" appeared.

On careful analysis, I found that all the folders in my machine (Windows 7 x64) appears to be "Read Only". Changing the property doesn't help.

Can someone help/provide pointer to me in resolving this "Read Only" issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's no issue, except that the Windows Explorer GUI is confusing in this respect.  If you use the `attrib` command from the command line I bet you'll find the read-only flag isn't set on those directories, it's just that Explorer doesn't think the read-only flag is meaningful for directories and represents that belief in a confusing way.

Comment: ... your original problem was probably that the executable file was locked by another process (perhaps your anti-virus software) or by Windows.  This seems to happen sometimes.  In the worst cases (luckily very rare) the only resolution is to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It is because our Company policy was updated without any precautions. And the antivirus blocked all .exe files